# Is it possible to force Serilog.Sink.File to start a new log file when application starts up?

Tags: .net, serilog

I'm using `Serilog.Sinks.File` and would like to get a fresh log file when my application starts up.

Is there any way to do that?

The logger always appends to the existing log file.

Comment: from looking at the source, pretty sure the answer is no. One reason is that from a concurrency point of view that would be a race. If using Seq (or other log search engines), you could log an app start and offset searches from that point forward.

Comment: as a hack, you could use `{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}` in the filename you supply...

Comment: @RubenBartelink - i was considering similar approach, but then the rolling mechanism will loose track of deleting files older than 31 days, i afraid.

Comment: @zuraff that depends on your rolling scheme config - it's just following your rules

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like this:

```
public static void CreateNextLogInSequence(string path, string prefix, DateTime timestamp, string suffix, string format, int? index = null)
{
    var target = new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}{3}{4}",
        path,
        prefix,
        timestamp.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        index == null ? string.Empty : ("_" + index.Value.ToString("000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
        suffix));
    if (target.Exists || index == null)
        CreateNextLogInSequence(path, prefix, timestamp, suffix, format, (index ?? 0) + 1);
    else
        target.Create().Close();
}
```

.. and use it like this:

```
.UseSerilog((context, services, config) =>
{
    ...

    CreateNextLogInSequence("Logs", "log-", DateTime.Now, ".txt", "yyyyMMdd");

    config.WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .WriteTo.File(path: $"Logs/log-.txt", rollOnFileSizeLimit: true, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            formatter: new ExpressionTemplate("{@t:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{@l:u3}] [{SourceContext}] {if @m = '[null]' then '' else @m}\n{@x}")));
}
```

This will create a brand new file in the sequence and simulate a rollover that Serilog will recognize. It will start using the freshly created file.